# MySQL subtract field with the field before

Tags: sql, mariadb, subtraction

I want to subtract two values, the current value, and value from the row before the current value at each value, basically creating a new table with only these new values, so that I can average them late.

Table structure looks like this:

```
-----------------------
id | keyTime   | millis| 
------------------------
1  | 22:00:00  | 10  | 
2  | 22:05:00  | 20  |
3  | 22:10:00  | 30  | 
4  | 22:15:00  | 40  |
```

And I would like to subtract like this:

---

```
id | dif    |
-------------
1  | 10-0   | 
2  | 20-10  |
3  | 30-20  | 
4  | 40-30  |
```

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you can use the `LAG()` function. Do you have MySQL 8.x or the old 5.x?

Comment: 10.1.37 MariaDB

Comment: You'll need MariaDB 10.2 to use `LAG()`. You're better off with another solution, such as Gordon's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, (millis - coalesce(prev_millis, 0)) as diff
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.millis
              from t t2
              where t2.keyTime < t.keyTime
              order by t2.keyTime desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_millis
      from t
     ) t;
```

This assumes that the `id` is unreliable.  With the `id` values you have shown, you could simply use a `left join`.

Comment: Good answer. I never think of using `LIMIT` inside a table expression. Will need to get it into my brain. It's as if MySQL had "lateral" table expressions by default.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . Lateral joins are a generalization of correlated subqueries.  The latter have been in SQL since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I think a left join would be the best solution (if your ids will always be consecutive)

```
SELECT `t`.`id`,`t`.`millis`-COALESCE(`t2`.`millis`,0) AS `diff`
FROM `t`
LEFT JOIN `t` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`id` = `t`.`id`-1
```

Otherwise, I'd use a sub-query

```
SELECT `id`,`millis` - COALESCE((SELECT `millis` FROM `t` AS `t2` WHERE `id` < `t`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1),0) AS `diff`
FROM `t`
```